# How to remove first row from multiple files either through command or script

Tags: unix

I have multiple source files start with ABC*, I have to remove first row from each file, some one please let me know how to reach.

As i am new to Unix, i can able to remove for single file like "tail -n +2 ".
Don't know how to remove for multiple files.

Comment: Please provide a code example so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Thanks! But, it's standard procedure for **you** to post examples when you ask a question on Stack Overflow. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further information.

Comment: Hi, Hudson please find the example,. My files look like ABC123.dat, ABC234.dat,. ABC345.dat,. ABC675.dat,.  From each file i need to remove first record(entire line).  Like that i have lot of files each file name start with ABC*.

Comment: Once again, it's best for you to post an example block of code in your initial question. The below examples were posted by other users, not you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop:

```
for file in abc*; do
    tail -n +2 $file
done
```

If you need the edits to be saved, you can add a `>` redirect after the `tail` command to send the results of `tail` to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ ls
bar baz foo
$ awk 'FNR==1{close(f);f="new-"FILENAME}FNR>1{print>f}' foo bar baz
$ ls 
bar  baz  foo  new-bar  new-baz  new-foo
```

Explained:

```
FNR==1 { close(f); f="new-"FILENAME }  # 1st of each file, close previous file
FNR>1  { print>f }                     # after the 1st record print to file
```

You can use `awk '...' ABC*` as filename(s). `new-ABC*`s will be created.